# Mapbox-GL Angular - mgl-layer add symbology via .json file

Tags: angularjs, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Building my first angular app, want to use mapbox-gl to display my own data. Having the  with nested  tag, I have problems to symbolize the layer based on a .json file, in which different paint patterns for the data are stored.

How can I access a .json file and include it in the mgl-layer?

```
<mgl-map
  [style]="my_style"
  [zoom]="[8]"
>

<mgl-layer
 id="routes"
 type="line"
 sourceLayer="route"
 [source] = getting my own data from server
>
</mgl-layer>
</mgl-map>
```

The .json file looks similar to this

```
{
"id":"route_main"
"type":"line"
"paint": ...
},
{
"id":"route_secondary"
"type":"line"
"paint": ...
},
{
"id":"route_minor"
"type":"line"
"paint": ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to dynamically initialize layers (the example is adapted from official [Mapbox GL JS Docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/))

Assuming the data for layers is stored in JSON file and represented in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "id": "museums",
    "type": "circle",
    "source": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "mapbox://mapbox.2opop9hr"
    },
    "layout": {
      "visibility": "visible"
    },
    "paint": {
      "circle-radius": 8,
      "circle-color": "rgba(55,148,179,1)"
    },
    "sourceLayer": "museum-cusco"
  },
  //..
]



<mgl-map
  [style]="'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  [center]="center"
>

  <mgl-layer *ngFor="let layer of layersData;"
    [id]="layer.id"
    [type]="layer.type"
    [source]="layer.source"
    [sourceLayer]="layer.sourceLayer"
    [paint]="layer.paint"
    [layout]="layer.layout"
  ></mgl-layer>
</mgl-map>



export class AppComponent {
  center = [-71.97722138410576, -13.517379300798098];
  zoom = 15;
  layersData: null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.loadLayers().subscribe(data => {
      this.layersData = data;
    });
  }

  public loadLayers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/LayersData.json");
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-le7qpd)

Comment: if i update layersData dynamically, then it shows issues like error.handler.service.ts:29 ERROR: Error: There is already a source with this ID